# I want to know all about the db&table specific information of the Hive Metastore

Tags: hive, metastore

I want to know about the db.table specific information of the hive metastore. 
but I could not find it. 
(Hive metastore ALL DB & Table & Column description...)

I want to create a data catalog service with Hive metastore.
I know DBs, COLUMNS_V2, SERDE, etc..Hive metastore DB , but I do not know all of them.

And I want to get more information on what information I can use.

How can find out Hive metastore table definition document?

Comment: Your question is off-topic since it asks for opinions and suggestions and it has no programming features.